# how to make gvim close without prompting "Save changes to Untitled?"

Tags: vim

I often use gvim to view a few lines of log, so I could add new-lines to make it easy to read. These are not at all important text so I don't have a need to save to file. The problem is when I shutdown my computer, gvim would prompt with a dialog-box "Save changes to Untitled?", and the computer does not shutdown. I want to get rid of this prompt. Any help, or direction to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

I have reviewed posting on vim/gvim. None of the posting addresses my problem. They all had to do with user closing vim/gvim and needed a prompt; my case is just the opposite. I was looking to use a window close event, but didn't find anything yet.

===== more information =====

I only want to get rid of the dialog window shown below, not any other type of warning. Thanks for the responses I have received so far. I am also trying to get this to work.

[image: gvim dialog box when existing unsaved unnamed file]

Comment: have you thought about the situation that you have written some **important** stuff in your gvim, then you forget saving your work and clicked shutdown pc? Perhaps you can achieve what you want by scripting, but it is dangerous. From your description, I guess you are working on windows system. what it is gonna happen when you open a notepad/word/excel..., type something without saving, and shutdown the pc? The work you typed will be discarded without a warning/confirmation? I don't have windows to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses, especially the one from @DJMcMayhem, below is what I got to work exactly as I want it.  a) if I am editing an existing file, or had given it a file name, I will still get a prompt, and will not lose any edit.  b) when I shutdown my computer and I had some scratch buffer, I will not get a prompt "Save changes to Untitled?". This way windows will shutdown.

```
function! CloseOnShutdown()
    if eval('@%')==''
        set nomodified
    endif
endfunction

autocmd FocusLost * call CloseOnShutdown()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke `gvim` in such a situation, invoke it as `gvim '+set bt=nofile' FILE`.  This will tell Vim that the buffer is not related to a file and will allow you to exit without saving.

If this is too difficult to remember or too burdensome to type, you can create a shell alias or a shell script in a directory in your `PATH` (e.g., `~/bin`) and then invoke that instead.  Similar things can be done on Windows, but there the steps to make it work are left as an exercise for the reader.

You can also create a command in your `.vimrc` which sets the current buffer to be a scratch buffer that need not be saved by doing something like the following, if that's more to your liking:

```
command! Scratch setl bt=nofile
```

Comment: You can set an shell alias like this: `alias vimscratch="vim -c 'setlocal bt=nofile bh=wipe nobl noswapfile nu'"` and then run `command | vimscratch -`. I have used this command a bunch of times and if by any chance you need to save the file you have to run: `set bt=`. For more read `:h buftype`.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented under your question. If you work in a normal buffer, you should exit it with `:q!` to discard the changes you made.

But if you want to quit vim without confirmation, you should work in a "scratch" buffer. 
Regarding what is a scratch buffer:

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11310/what-is-a-scratch-window

You can create a mapping to set these three options:

```
  :setlocal buftype=nofile
  :setlocal bufhidden=hide
  :setlocal noswapfile
```

Or simply way, there are a lot of scratch plugins available, you can choose one.
https://github.com/mtth/scratch.vim

https://github.com/ViKomprenas/scratch.vim

https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=664

https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2odei7/scratchvim_a_scratch_window_that_stays_out_of/

Comment: Another way to discard any kind of buffer it is typing the "normal command" `ZQ`

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with it a bit, I think this should work:

```
autocmd ExitPre * q!
```

One problem with this is that it will make it very easy for you to lose unsaved changes. Here's a slightly more sophisticated version:

```
function! CloseUnnamed()
  if eval('@%') == ''
    q!
  endif
endfunction

autocmd ExitPre * call CloseUnnamed()
```

This will only automatically close unnamed buffers. If you have unnamed changes in a named buffer (because you were editing a file) this will still halt shutdown. You could also make it so that you automatically save unnamed buffers when you shutdown:

```
function! CloseUnnamed()
  if eval('@%') == ''
    q!
  else
    wq!
  endif
endfunction

autocmd ExitPre * call CloseUnnamed()
```

But I don't really recommend this. I'd rather review the unsaved changes.

Comment: getting below error (maybe I am using older version):
Error detected while processing C:\Users\<user>\\_vimrc:

line   41:

E216: No such group or event: ExitPre * q!